# Get raised exception from stored procedure as output variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, output-parameter

I am having problem in storing the exception raised from a stored procedure.

For example I am having two stored procedures `P_Add` And `P_GetAdd`.
`P_Add` returns an exception on divide by zero as shown,
procedure `P_GetAdd` executes `P_Add`.
I want to return the exception raised by `P_Add` to the code from where `P_GetAdd` is executed.
`P_Add` excpets a parameter which was not supplied is the error.
Help me to get the result. 
Thanks.

```
create procedure P_add
(
    @ErrorMessage varchar (100) OUTPUT
)
as
Declare @a int
Declare @b int
declare @c int

set @a = 1
set @b = 0

Begin try
    SET @c = @a/@b
end try
begin catch
   SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
End catch

create procedure P_getADD
(
@ErrorMessage1 varchar (100) OUTPUT
)
AS

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sysobjects
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[P_add]')
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1   
        )
BEGIN
    EXEC P_add  @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage1
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question, you need to mark `@ErrorMessage1` as `output` when executing the `P_add` stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_getADD
(
    @ErrorMessage1 varchar (100) OUTPUT
)
AS

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sysobjects
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[P_add]')
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1   
        )
BEGIN
    EXEC P_add @ErrorMessage1 OUTPUT
END
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. But I guess I can also use RAISERROR () to throw the error to the parent Stored Procedure.

Comment: The answer was to the question that was posted. If you find this answer correct, please mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved. If you came up with a better answer, please post it and accept it.